# Hibernate validator regex not resolved correctly

Tags: regex, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm validating a class with the following annotation :

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(00330|330)\\d{9}$", message="${msidsn.bad.format}")
private String msisdn;
```

where I want to validate all numbers starting with 00330 or 330 and followed by whatever 9 digits.

The pattern works fine with the usual java regex but always fails with the hibernate validator...

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<SMSObject>> constraintViolations =  validator.validate(sms);
```

→ Returns a ConstraintViolation.

Normal regex checks fine :

```
boolean valid = false;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(00330|330)\\d{9}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("00330112345678");
if (matcher.find()) {
    valid = true;
}
```

Any insights on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What the property you are annotating with @Pattern? When you say it always fails with Hibernate Validator, what do you mean? You get a ConstraintViolation or is there another error? How does this code you posted relate to the question?

Comment: @Hardy I have edited the question to be more explicit. Yes I get a ConstraintViolation with the corresponding message. The code posted below goes with what I said : a normal regex check works fine.